# Position sticky not working on table header when overflow is set to scroll / auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I found lot of solution but nothing worked hence posting this question again. I have a table having horizontal scroll on that. I tried to set the table header sticky, i am able to do it using `poition:sticky` but scrolling stopped working.

Is there any way to achieve both using css?

Here is a simple [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbmv3ztw/) for your references.

***update***
Instead of adding a scrollbar on table body i need it to behave same with main page scroll. Any pure JS or angular solution is also acceptable for this. **Header should be sticky when user will scroll through the page not table**.

Comment: Its working fine for me. The table is scrolling horizontally and the page is scrolling as well.

Comment: @Ritz OP wants to both sticky header and overflow-x to work. "Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table."

Comment: Its working if you set these properties `.responsive {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}`

Comment: @Awais, But this will add one extra scrollbar which i don't prefer here.

Comment: Ok then set it to `max-height` after record reach that limit auto scroll comes OR set to `vh` view-port height

Comment: Just add height to the .responsive class.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on css alone then if you add specified height to your 'responsive' class, the header would stick but only inside the responsive div.

You could achieve that if you'd replace your table element with separated div's for headers and body.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .responsive {
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This can help you in giving you the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Is `div.responsive` a must? Here's my solution without it.

I added a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to separate the header and body.

`<thead>` and `<tbody>` gets their own scroll bar. `display: block` is required to that the set width is applied to `<thead>`:

```
thead,
tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 400px;
}
```

To make sure that all cells have the same width, apply `min-width` to all of them (just pick a reasonable width):

```
th,
td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 70px;
}
```

To make the header sticky, you can apply `position: sticky` on `<thead>`, also hide the scroll on `<thead>` because you'll be adding a script to sync the horizontal scrolls:

```
thead {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```js
const thead = document.querySelector('thead');
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

tbody.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  thead.scrollLeft = tbody.scrollLeft;
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 400px;
}

thead {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 70px;
}

th {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Responsive Table</h2>
  <p>If you have a table that is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table.</p>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```